# How to override KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry in KafkaBootstrapConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I need to add some logic to KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry - i want to register additional listener for every topic (i want to create chain of retry topics consumers with different time of polling), that i create with @Listener annotation. And for that purpose i want to try to override registerListenerContainer method and to implement logic there.

The first step i made is to add default configuration the same as in KafkaBootstrapConfiguration. But after that all my tests fail and in some reason my listeners don't consume anything. And if i don't add bean everything works fine.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class CustomKafkaBootstrapConfiguration {

  @Bean(name = KafkaListenerConfigUtils.KAFKA_LISTENER_ENDPOINT_REGISTRY_BEAN_NAME)
  public KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry defaultKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry() {
    return new KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry(){
        @Override
        public void registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpoint endpoint, KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> factory) {
            //i need to add logic here
            super.registerListenerContainer(endpoint, factory);
        }
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied your override and everything worked as expected.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So57674940Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(new Class<?>[] { So57674940Application.class, So57674940ApplicationConfig.class }, args);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so57674940", topics = "so57674940")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
class So57674940ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean(name = KafkaListenerConfigUtils.KAFKA_LISTENER_ENDPOINT_REGISTRY_BEAN_NAME)
    public KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry defaultKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry() {
        return new KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry() {
            @Override
            public void registerListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpoint endpoint,
                    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<?> factory) {
                // i need to add logic here
                System.out.println("in custom registry");
                super.registerListenerContainer(endpoint, factory);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

and

```
in custom registry
2019-08-27 11:20:36.251  INFO 33460 --- [o57674940-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [so57674940-0]
```